# Worksheet change Event working like after update event of combobox

Tags: excel, vba

Ok i want to make a searchable drop down list data validation without using helper column or combobox control...So how can i accomplish this..Everything is working fine but let say if i put at then click drop down arrow it will not calculate the worksheet change event..I want to run the worksheet change event every time value change in a certain cell..Suppose if i type at then worksheet change event should run 2 times..I mean every time i click in a keyboard alphabet then the worksheet change event need to run.How can i accomplish this...
Here is my code:

Worksheet Change Event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DestinationRng As Range, SourceRng As Range
Set SourceRng = Range("A1:A25")
Set DestinationRng = Range("C1:C25")
If Not Application.Intersect(DestinationRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    'Target.Validation.Delete
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        DVDL SourceRng, Target, ""
    Else
        DVDL SourceRng, Target, Range(Target.Address).Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Here is worksheet selection change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DestinationRng As Range, SourceRng As Range
Set SourceRng = Range("A1:A25")
Set DestinationRng = Range("C1:C25")
'    'If Target = ActiveCell Then Debug.Print yes
Debug.Print "Active:" & ActiveCell.Address
Debug.Print Target.Address

If Not Application.Intersect(DestinationRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        DVDL SourceRng, Target, ""
    Else
        DVDL SourceRng, Target, Range(Target.Address).Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the data validation sub procedure:

```
Public Sub DVDL(SourceRng As Range, PlaceRng As Range, SearchTxt As String)
Dim arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant

If SourceRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng.Value))
ElseIf SourceRng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng.Value)
End If
arr = RemoveDuplicateS(arr)
If SearchTxt = "" Then
    arr2 = arr
Else
    arr2 = Filter(arr, SearchTxt, , vbTextCompare)
End If
For Each el In arr2
    Debug.Print el
Next el
If LBound(arr2) <> UBound(arr) Then
'PlaceRng.Select
With PlaceRng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arr2, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
    
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the code for Removing duplicate value from source range:Not required if source contain unique value

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicateS(arr As Variant) As Variant
'From this function we return an array from an sorted array.
'It doesn't required extra space in memory because we use same array.
Dim i As Long, j As Long
If IsEmpty(arr) Then
    RemoveDuplicateS = arr(0) 'If incoming array is empty then return empty one.
Else
    j = LBound(arr)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1  'Run loop from first one to second last one.
        If arr(i) <> arr(i + 1) Then                    'if arr(5)<>arr(6) then put put the arr(5) value to the unique list.
            arr(j) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1                                             'Increase the j for indexing.
        End If
    Next i
    arr(j) = arr(UBound(arr))                          'Put the last data to unique list.
    ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To j)     'Delete the extra data from the array.
    RemoveDuplicateS = arr                           'Return the array.
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please do not include external links to excel files in your question.

Comment: If someone wants to see the file. so i attach that.Ok.